# Passing values - all in the same file - not working

Tags: jquery, ajax, openlayers

I need your advise. I'm new to ajax and jquery. I'm using postgresql 9.1 /postGIS 2.0 /openlayers/geoserver and apache.

I managed getting a feature's id when clicked on the map (openlayers), using javascript.

Using ajax I m trying to pass this value to a PHP value and perform a query. Openlayers, jquery, javascript and ajax work fine but php never gets the value. Here is my code snippets.

```
//this is inside openlayers init function
function selected_feature(event){
//getting the id
var sf = event.feature.fid;
var sfs = sf.split(".");
var sff = sfs[1]
//ajax
$(document).ready(function()
{
 $.post("map.php", { jas: 'sff'});
});

//the php code snippet, after openlayers
$_SESSION['blah'] = $_POST['jas']; 
$blah= $_SESSION['blah'];
echo $blah;
 $queryd='
  SELECT
   pins.p_name 
  FROM
    pins
    WHERE
    pins.p_id='.$blah;
 //fetching to fill array
 $resultd=pg_query($conn, $queryd);
 $nord=pg_num_rows($resultd);
 $d=0;
  while($arrayd=pg_fetch_array($resultd)){
      $name[$d]=$arrayd['p_name'];
    $d++;
        echo $arrayd['p_name'];
                echo $arrayd[$d];

    }
```

Problem is php's echos not working and query not working at all. I know this question sounds like a dublicate but I believe is different because all the code is in the same file (named map.php). Plus, there is some web-mapping on the background. I dont even know if one of the web-mapping programms causing the problem.

Please advise

Thank you.

EDIT
I just edited the ajax part. I've replaced with this

```
jQuery.post("map.php", { jas : "sff" }, function(data) {
  //  alert(data);
  });
```

...still no luck

EDIT #2

According to [this](http://wabism.com/ajax-tutorial-with-jquery/) tutorial I edited my code. So now I have this jquery in my map.php

```
jQuery.post("testone.php", { jas : sff }, function(data) {
  alert(data);
  });
```

And in the testone.php this php code

```
<?php
  $jas = $_POST['jas'];
     print $jas;
?>
```

map.php actually alerts the data. But, one more thing. How to pass the data back to map.php as an PHP value, so I can also activate the query? Most tutorials out there are about alerting the data or put them in a `<div>`. I want to use php. Something like

```
   jQuery.post("testone.php", { jas : sff }, function(data) {
    //put returned data in a php var
          });
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd move your PHP to another file and then you'll need to `echo json_encode($name);` and handle your returned data within a callback handler on your jQuery post.

`$.post('new.php',{jas:'sff'},function(data){ //do something cool with data[0] through the last index of the array });`

Comment: @ Jarealist Ok first of all, thanks for the anser. I Just edited my question...You mean perform the query and render it's results in another file? But I need it all to be on the same file...Anyway, if two different files is the only way, how `include_once(second-file.php)` sounds? So user does not know anything, does not have to go to another file to see the results.

Comment: That's the beauty of AJAX. The users wouldn't be routed to another page. Only the work would be done on another page and be returned to the page through the AJAX.

Your PHP code needs to echo the array through the json_encode function like 
`while($arrayd=pg_fetch_array($resultd)){
      $name[$d]=$arrayd['p_name'];
    $d++;

    }
 echo json_encode($name);
`.

Comment: Ok I think I got the philosophy, but, not the technical part. Can you give me a link or a tutorial or something? A guideline? So I can study it?

Comment: I did a quick googling of "php jquery ajax tutorial" and found [this](http://williamjxj.wordpress.com/2011/10/02/jquery-json-and-phpjson_encode-example/).

Comment: According to this simple tutorial [link](http://wabism.com/ajax-tutorial-with-jquery/) I created two files. Map.php contains the jquery and testone.php contains the php. Now, map.php actually alerts the value of the var named sff. So ok... But how to pass this value from testone.php back to map.php, something like `$slevinWeirdo=$_POST[jas]`. Not alert it, pass it in php, to also activate the query...